# Can we build our own image of Raspberry Pi OS?

Tags: raspbian, raspberry-pi-os

According to Raspberry Pi,

> Many operating systems are available for Raspberry Pi, including **Raspberry Pi OS, our official supported operating system**, and operating systems from other organisations.

It seems this OS is built from Debian 11 or 12.

- Is the infrastructure to build this OS public?
- Can we build our own OS from Debian 11 or 12?
- Are these repeatable builds? Can we confirm the version on the site is produced by following the same process with the upstream source?

Comment: I noticed this when I was poking around earlier: https://salsa.debian.org/raspi-team/image-specs ("Option 2").

Comment: PiOS is built with https://github.com/RPi-Distro/pi-gen